# How to solve the rule S2295 in Sonarqube 6.5?, in V.5.6.6 this rule did not report error

Tags: c#, sonarqube

-How to solve the rule S2259 ?, I am using Sonarqube 6.5 and in V.5.6.6 the rule did not report error.

-I have reviewed the comments about what is posted in this rule, but I reported it because I am using the new sonarqube version with MSBuild and started reporting it. Additionally, no compilable examples are proposed in the description of this rule S2295.

-I have the sonar-csharp-plugin-6.3.0.2862 plugin, I have checked the java version installed and it is java 8.

-see screens of the cases where more is presented:

Thank you for the collaboration you can give me.

[image: Findings-S2295]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of each analyzer pre-loaded in the server is updated with each release of the SonarQube platform. If the rule existed in the version of SonarC# you were running under SonarQube 5.6.6, it obviously wasn't as "smart".

Regarding the lack of compliant solutions, when there are many ways of fixing an issue, demonstrating only one could be misleading, so compliant solutions might simply be omitted.

For your particular case, you seem to be using `ReferenceEquals` to do a null-check. It's far simpler and clearer to do that with `ManejoRetencion == null`